# all the elements in foreach or parallel foreach won't loop when a task inside is started in c#

Tags: c#, foreach, task, parallel.foreach

```
var seldir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
Parallel.ForEach(seldir.EnumerateFiles(), files =>
{
    if (files.Extension.Equals(".txt"))
    {
        Task text = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => opentext(files.Name));
    }
    else if (files.Extension.Equals(".doc"))
    {
        Task doc = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => opendoc(files.Name));
    }
});
```

Once the code finds a text file, it starts the task to call another function in the if condition, later no matter the any no. of files enumerated, the code just doesn't reach elseif part even though a .doc extension file is found. I need to open all the text and doc files that are found in the folder. Please help.

Comment: Your code does not even compile. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Additionally, why use `StartNew`? You are **already in** a new `Task` (since you are using `Parallel.ForEach`. Why spin up **another** one?

Comment: There's no such thing as `elseif` in c#. Are you sure you have the right language? Also, you're creating a lot of tasks that you never await... was that intentional?

Comment: @mjwills I have a UI, when I click a button it is redirected to this function, I'm trying to create multiple tasks because I want the UI thread to be running.

Comment: @mjwills All I want to do is, from a user selected folder, enumerate the files, parse .txt and .doc files(different function). the code is using task inorder to keep the UI elements active while trying to parse these files.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than make all those separate background calls, it is far simpler to extract all the logic to a single background method.

```
public async void OpenFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run( OpenFiles );
}


async Task OpenFiles()
{
    var seldir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var extensions = new string[] { ".txt", ".doc" };
    var files = seldir.EnumerateFiles().Where( x => extensions.Any( y => x.Extension == y));
    foreach (var f in files) opentext(f.Name);
}
```